# Possible to use drop down selection in one cell to change another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In one column, in one cell I have this:

```
=COUNTIFS(D5:D11,">10",D5:D11,"<10000")
```

Where it says `>10` I would like to be able to use a drop down menu in another column and cell to be able to change that `10` to `20`, `30`, `40`, `50` etc..

So it would instead be `>20` or `>30` or `>40` etc.

Can this be done? I can't seem to find anything anywhere about it.

I did try putting the drop down box's column letter and row number (which is `A5`) where the `10` is, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Try =COUNTIFS(D5:D11,>A5,D5:D11,"<10000")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just replace the 10 with `& CELL LOCATION`

See below:

```
=COUNTIFS(D5:D11,">"&A5,D5:D11,"<10000")
```

Comment: @ArnieCunningham please accept as correct answer